# Can you simplify and solve the following expression?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you simplify and solve the following equation $\ddot{x}+\dfrac{\dot{x}^2}{x}=0$ where $x=x(u)$? My approach so far has been to trying break out $\frac{d}{du}$ from the equation so I then can set the term inside the brackets equal to a constant and then solve it easily. But I get stuck at the following point in my equations
$$
\ddot{x}+\dfrac{\dot{x}^2}{x}=\dfrac{d}{du}(\frac{1}{2}\dot{x})+\frac{d}{du}(\ln x)\dot{x}^2=0
$$
I did this simply by multiplying with $\dot{x}$. I don't know how to include $\dot{x}^2$ in the differention so I then can break out $\frac{d}{du}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take the derivative of $x\dot{x}$

Comment: Which is $x\ddot{x}+\dot{x}^2$

Comment: Thanks sir! You're a genius!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's multiply your equation by $x$, giving 
$$ x \ddot x + \dot x^2 = 0 $$
Now recall that this is the derivative of $x\dot x$, by the product rule, so we have 
$$ \frac d{du} (x\dot x) = 0 $$
Hence, $x \dot  x$ is constant, say 
$$ x \dot x = c $$
with $c \in \mathbf R$. Multiplying by two gives 
$$ 2x\dot x = c, $$
the left hand side is the derivative of $x^2$, by the chain rule, so we have 
$$ \frac d{du}(x^2) = c $$
so, for some $d \in \mathbf R$, we have 
$$ x^2 = cu + d $$
or $$ x = \sqrt{cu + d} $$

Answer (score 0):

$$\ddot{x}+\dfrac{\dot{x}^2}{x}=0,$$
then with $\dot x\ne 0$,
$$\frac{\ddot{x}}{\dot{x}}+\dfrac{\dot{x}}{x}=0.$$

By integration,

$$\log\dot x+\log x=C$$ or

$$2x\dot x=C$$

which gives us

$$x^2=Ct+C'.$$